# Why does the exception thrown from Socket.Receive report an exception in my program when the server closed the connection?

Tags: .net, sockets

I have a connection that I am closing in a server (another executable) using `Socket.Close()`. In my client on the `Socket.BeginReceive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)` call it throws a `SocketException` stating

```
An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

This gives me the impression that I am closing a connection that some thread has blocked on a `Socket.Receive()` or `Socket.EndReceive()`. Have I done something incorrectly here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested with Shutdown() before Close() recommendation for gracefuly closing the socket on the server side as [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wahsac9k.aspx) ?  I would think that a graceful close should not cause the client to report the connection as aborted, this should only happen if the connection is reset (TCP RST).